# FirebaseAuth object missing user creation and authentication methods

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm attempting to use Firebase Authentication in a Java/JVM REST service, but can't seem to find the method `signInWithUsernameAndPassword()` referenced in multiple documentations.

First of all, I believe I'm using the most recent version of the Maven library ([`com.google.firebase firebase-admin 4.0.2`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.firebase/firebase-admin/4.0.2)) which was originally intended for Android but should work just fine for Java/JVM as well, and obtain the FirebaseAuth object via `FirebaseAuth.getInstance()` as per the [official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/password-auth).

However, within that `FirebaseAuth` object, I only see two `createCustomToken()` overload methods and a method `verifyIdToken()`.  I don't see any of the user creation and authentication methods that I should according to the [official class reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth).

Anybody know what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: I should also note that I'm getting an actual "cannot find symbol" compile error if I try to build with a reference to the method signInWithUsernameAndPassword()

Comment: pls post the gradle dependencies u have added